# Interpretation of linear-regression p values when data does not come from linear model

Tags: regression, p-value

Suppose I observe $n$ samples of a response variable $y$, along with variables $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ which I think can help predict $y$.  I don't have any reason to believe that the underlying relationship between the variables is linear or close to linear, but as a simple baseline I start with a linear regression and look at the coefficients and $p$-values.  If I understand correctly, when constructing the $p$-value for the coefficient of $x_3$ the null hypothesis is

$$\mathcal{H}_0: y=\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\beta_3x_3+\epsilon$$ where $\beta_3=0$.

Then $p$-value gives the probability that we observe $n$ samples from this model, perform OLS to estimate the coefficients, and get an estimate $\hat{\beta_3}$ of $\beta_3$ whose magnitude is at least as large as the result of my regression.

In the case where I don't believe the data actually comes from, or is well approximated by, a linear model, I struggle to understand the significance of the $p$-values.  Can $p$-values be helpful in this context, and if so are there some general heuristics people use?  For example, is it reasonable to use the $p$-values as a type of feature selection?  i.e. if I have a large number of samples and the p-value for $\beta_3$ is not small, is it sensible to conclude that $x_3$ probably does not add much predictive value?

Comment: I suggest scatterplotting all independent variables versus the dependent variable to determine if any obvious data transformation, such as log or exp, might help in the regression. This is fast and a good "due diligence" item.

Comment: "Then p-value gives the probability that we observe n samples from this model" ... no, I don't think that's a correct understanding of a p-value. That sounds nearer to a description of a likelihood (though not quite correct if that's what it's meant to be). Note that p-value calculations are predicated on the model's assumptions (of which linearity is very important for regression). If they don't hold, the p-values might not mean much at all.

Comment: If your data is not linearly related then p-values and coefficients and SD's (pretty much everything) could be wrong and meaningless, since your model is wrong. And no, p-values are not used for feature selection.